# Как получить объект, внутри которого находится функция?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Есть ссылка на некоторую функцию `callBack`, находящуюся в неизвестном объекте. Возможно ли получить объект либо его название, в котором находится наша функция?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таком случае

```
 var callback = object.func;
```

Когда передаётся ссылка на функцию и известны возможные объекты, можно:

```
var objects = [
    {id: 1, func: function(){return 3;}},
    {id: 2, func: function(){return 2;}},
    {id: 3, func: function(){return 1;}}
];
var func = objects[1].func;
for(var i=objects.length;i--;){
    var obj = objects[i];
    for(var prop in obj){
        if(obj[prop] == func){
            console.log(obj); // {id: 2, func: function(){return 2;}}
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

ещё один вариант - во всех методах объектов преполагаемых для использования в качестве колбэка хранить ссылку на сам объект:

```
var obj = {possibleCallback: function(){...}};
obj.possibleCallback.root = obj;
```

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете все объекты занести в некий массив и затем сравнивать по строкам их функции?

Comment: ещё один вариант - во всех методах объектов преполагаемых для использования в качестве колбэка хранить ссылку на сам объект:

    var obj = {possibleCallback: function(){...}};
    obj.possibleCallback.root = obj;

Comment: >> obj.possibleCallback.root = obj;  >>      
А такое возможно. Может obj.possibleCallback.prototype.root=function()...  Или JS допускает такие конструкции?

Comment: любая функция - это всего лишь объект, следовательно ему можно динамически добавить то или иное свойство, если же вы добавите это свойство в прототип, то оно будет использовано для объектов пораждаемых этой функцией в качестве конструктора

Comment: Неплохой способ решения проблемы. Спасибо.